# rails 5 - Create channel per conversation by ActionCable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, chat, actioncable

I'm a new Rails developer and getting start to use ActionCable in Rails 5 to create a chat app.

The problem is that there are many chat examples in the Internet using ActionCable, but all of them are quite simple. They create a channel and all users connect to this channel can sent or read the messages from others.

For example, they create a Chat channel like this:

```
class ChatChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from 'messages'
  end

  def speak(data)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast('messages',
      message: render_message(data['message']))
  end

  private

  def render_message(message)
    ApplicationController.render(partial: 'messages/message',
                                 locals: { message: message })
  end
end
```

And in the client side, they connect to that channel

```
App.chat = App.cable.subscriptions.create "ChatChannel",
  received: (data) ->
    $('#messages').append(data.message)

  speak: (msg) ->
    @perform 'speak', message: msg
```

How can I create a channel per conversation between 2 users ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only thing that changes is the channel where you are subscribing to. Which in this case should be a specific conversation. You could have something like this:

## messages.coffee

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  messages = $("#messages-list")

  App.Messages = App.cable.subscriptions.create {
    channel: "MessagesChannel"
    # You can grab the conversation id as a data attribute from the messages container of your conversation and pass it as a parameter to the channel
    conversation_id: messages.data("conversation-id")
  },

  connected: ->

  disconnected: ->
    # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

  received: (data) ->
    messages.append(data["message"])
    $("#new_message")[0].reset();
```

## messages_channel.rb

```
class MessagesChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "conversation_#{params['conversation_id']}_channel"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

## messages_controller.rb

```
# You can have something like this in your create action
def create
    message = @conversation.messages.build(message_params)
    message.user = current_user
    message.save

    ActionCable.server.broadcast "conversation_#{message.conversation.id}_channel",
      message: render_message(message)

    head :ok
end

private

  def set_conversation
    @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
  end

  def render_message(message)
    render partial: "messages/message", locals: { message: message }
  end
```

Comment: Thanks. This is absolutely a way I've already used to deal with that problem

Comment: Glad it helped! Mark it as accepted if it was what you needed.

Comment: I don't think this would work if you don't have a `conversation_id` in the url. would you mind advising on you'd do that? I'm currently working on this but the conversation is displayed on an index page that lists all of the conversations. Think of messenger.com

Comment: is there any reason you set up `MessagesChannel` but stream from `conversation_channel`?